# I added Doctype tag and changed button's height

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="searchbox">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="src-txt" class="src-txt"/>
        <input type="submit" value="" name="src-btn" class="src-btn"/>
    </form>
</div>


.searchbox {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 3%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.src-txt {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #3682c4;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.src-btn {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #3682c4;
    background-image: url("../content/src_img.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

This is code it's working fine but after I add !DOCTYPE html at head search button's height decreased.

I can't understand what changed.

What is the reason?

What should I change on my code?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just increase the height after adding the !DOCTYPE html? 
Is your html tag set to 100% height? Sometimes that has caused issues with my code.